# created user in mongo with read role can insert

Tags: mongodb, function, authentication

I've created a user in mongo for this database with read access only,
but when I login in robomongo I can insert and even create new collections in test2 database

is there anything wrong?

```
use test2
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "user",
     pwd: "123",
     roles: [ "read"]
   }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you haven't enabled authentication on your `mongod` yet. 
 You have to enable authentication before it will limit your users based on their user priviliges.  From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) (emphasis mine):

> Enabling access control on a MongoDB deployment enforces authentication, requiring users to identify themselves. **When accessing a MongoDB deployment that has access control enabled, users can only perform actions as determined by their roles.**

So, if you add a `--auth` flag to your `mongod` and start that up, when you connect in via RoboMongo or the shell or wherever else, your user will only have read access on `test2` (and the other system databases that `read` grants access to).  Note that you will probably want to create an admin user as specified in that documentation before running with the `--auth` flag, assuming that you're going to want to keep that flag active for the rest of the time you're running your `mongod`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and saving my time after reading and testing lots of ways of creating
multiple roles and users and trial and error methods in 3 days. 
Cheers

Comment: hero! I forgot that I hadn't enabled on all members of my replica set